# Can I load JQuery twice using iFrame?

Tags: jquery, iframe

Can someone who have JQuery experience have a look at my following description and give me some advice:

Default.aspx: This page has the JQuery reference at its  section.
LoginControl.aspx: This page also has JQuery reference at its  section.

In Default.aspx, there is a

So when Default.aspx is open, it loads the JQuery.js library， and when the iFrame is open, it will load the JQuery second time because LoginControl.aspx loads it， am I correct??

I am not sure if this will cause problem or its normal? two Reference will be load into different scope ? will they conflict potentially??

I don't know other solutions, I have to use the JQuery library in both aspx pages, if I don't include the reference in the LoginControl.aspx, then I can't use JQuery, it give me error.

At the moment it looks find with having Jquery in both pages' header section, but I am not sure if this is OK?? for all the browsers??

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure if this will cause problem or its normal? two Reference will be load into different scope ? will they conflict potentially?

This is normal.  The libraries will operate within their own scopes.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually clone the original jQuery object by, for example:

```
window.$ = parent.window.$;
```

Furthermore, it is also possible to use in the embedded frame another (version) jQuery, the scope is differen, it's up to you if you want the user to execute two http request for actually one file!

Edit: Changed it to a better version of cloning it.

Comment: thanks for the reply, could you please give me a bit more of detail? where should I write those code? in the LoginControl.aspx?

Comment: In the LoginControl.aspx I would write something like:
`window.$ = parent.window.$;`
That way it's even easier. Be aware that if you use jQuery as the identifier instead of $ you need to assign that one.